# Add scraped data bellow the previous scraped data in the same excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to scrap data from a website using Excel and I have a problem that each extraction of data is inserted into new sheet while I want the new scraped data to be inserted bellow the previous data , first I have a sheet that has the links of all webpages that from the data are scraped .. my VBA codes are :

```
Sub adds()
For x = 1 To 316
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
mystr = " "
mystr = Cells(x, 1)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
'CommandType = 0
        .Name = "?q=ÍäÇä&daleel=mtn&do=search&page=2"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does what you are asking it to, adding a new worksheet for each value of x with this line:
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

Comment: @peakpeak no this code is adding each data in a new sheet I asked about adding data in one sheet where the new data will be inserted bellow the previous scraped data

Comment: Yes, the code is adding a new sheet for each loop as you've instructed it to. Remove the line I mentioned in my previous comment and amend the code as appropriate

Comment: @peakpeak when I delete it it gives me an error

Comment: @peakpeak can you rewrite the code for me please?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a programming service. Pure info: My company can do it if you pay me.

Comment: @peakpeak If I had money I wouldn't came to stackoverflow